Is there any easy tool to write raw transactions with a memo?
The idea is to build a complex transaction that have many outputs and some of them are MEMOs (using OP_RETURN) and spend one (or many) UTXOs.
A GUI tool would be awesome, but a CLI tool would also work. The important stuff is adding visibility for the fee for example, as a bad constructed transaction could be quite expensive.
In this this looking like question Electrum is mentioned, but it does not support adding a memo (as far as I understand).

Standard transactiions can only have a single OP_RETURN output

It seems that there is a special syntax in Electrum to send an OP_RETURN memo on the GUI when sending to many:
script(OP_RETURN 5468697320697320612074657374),0
tb1qerzrlxcfu24davlur5sqmgzzgsal6wusda40er,0.00003

The syntax seems to not documented, but it is mentioned on some unit tests.
As far as I could test, the OP_RETURN should be a HEX encoded string. Here is the resulting transaction

Why would you write memos into the transaction instead of storing them in your wallet and backing up your wallet?!

To interact with others, like Maya chain for example, that use those memos for some functionality.
